# How to add two time values stored as decimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time, type-conversion, sqldatatypes, azure-sql-managed-instance

I need to add two columns which stores time values as decimals 
example: 
1.) 8.30+0.32 = 9.02 (output should be 9.03 not 8.62)

The above mentioned example is working fine and is an actual output of the below SQL.

I wrote the below SQL which works fine predominantly, but I find few cases where the addition is not proper

Example: 3.57+5.25=18.44

```
SELECT
case when B.Column_B is null then A.Column_A
when B.Column_B is not null then 
replace(CONVERT(varchar(5), 
DATEADD(ss,(SUM((DATEPART(hh, replace(isnull(a.Column_A,0.00),'.',':'))*3600) + (DATEPART(mi,replace(isnull(a.Column_A,0.00),'.',':'))*60)) +
SUM((DATEPART(hh, replace(isnull(b.Column_B,0.00),'.',':'))*3600) + (DATEPART(mi,replace(isnull(b.Column_B,0.00),'.',':'))*60))),0),108) ,':','.')
End as "Total_Hours"
```

I am not able to find where this is going wrong in the above mentioned case. Is there anything wrong here or is there any better way of handling this addition

Comment: Why can't you use the time type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Value01 DECIMAL(9,2) = 8.30
       ,@value02 DECIMAL(9,2) = 0.32;

SELECT CONCAT 
       (
            (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', CAST(REPLACE(@Value01, '.', ':') AS TIME)) +  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', CAST(REPLACE(@value02, '.', ':') AS TIME))) / 60
           ,'.'
           ,RIGHT((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', CAST(REPLACE(@Value01, '.', ':') AS TIME)) +  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', CAST(REPLACE(@value02, '.', ':') AS TIME))) % 60 + 100, 2)
       );
```

First, convert to `TIME` and get the total number of minutes. Then, format the minutes to `Time` but using `.` instead `:`.

Comment: Great this works fine Thanks. But, what was the issue with the conversion which I have done. Does doing the conversion other way around does not work?

Comment: @Venkat I did not debug your code. There are different ways to solve an issue in T-SQL - you need to find usually the most efficient one in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
declare @v1 DECIMAL(9,3) = 4.369,  -- 9 characters with 3 decimal places.
@v2 DECIMAL(9,3) = 3.368  -- 9 characters with 3 decimal places.
print @v1 + @v2
```

**Output**

7.737